# I need any falsy value (false, null, zero, undefined) to be displayed as false in toggle quasar

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

[description toggle quasar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt4Gp.jpg)

`<q-toggle toggle-indeterminate indeterminate-value="2" v-model="frecVisCli.DIA_1"/>`

the property of my object comes as undefined what I need is that when it is undefined the toggle is to the left

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try false-value="null"?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).